# using rglob to recursively search and save files to folder

Tags: python, glob

I have this chunk of python code where I need to search all files inside the DATA folder that matches with .asc extension files,

```
for path in Path('DATA').rglob('*.asc'):
    print(path.name)
```

indeed the code finds all files matching that pattern and then prints them, but I also need to open the content of all those files and store it on a list and then save it in an excel file.

I am using this to do it

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
content = []

for path in Path('DATA').rglob('*.asc'):
    with open(name) as fn:
        content = fn.readlines()
        df = pd.read_csv(path.name, skiprows=0, encoding="ascii", engine='python', sep='|', delimiter=None, index_col=False, header=0, skipinitialspace=True)
        content.append(df)
        data_frame = pd.concat(content)
        print(data_frame.head(10))
```

but I am still getting the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '205479_501.asc'

It seems like it is no finding any of the files or storing any files in the content list and then open them and reading them with pandas.

Comment: `open(name)` should be `open(str(path))`.

Comment: What is name? If it is the file path of the file then why do you read it with pandas also? Also it should be str(path) (just path I guess is fine) or something along those lines like @enzo suggests

Comment: You can open `Path` objects with its `open()` function. (`with path.open('rt') as fd:`) but I'm not sure why you need to use a `DataFrame` if you're only going to print the first 10 lines.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, and thanks enzo, I think your suggestion worked.